I would like to know how to read all the data from a Zigbee dongle via the serial port using Python
I would like to know how to read all the data from a Zigbee dongle via the serial port using Python. I've tried several codes but haven't been able to retrieve any data.
The Zigbee dongle should provide key data such as the MAC address of the chip paired with the dongle, sensor data like PM, CO2, and other values.

Please share the code you tried and the errors you got. Otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I think you should use the pyserial module.
Here a simple example of how you can do this:
import serial

def read_from_zigbee(serial_port, baud_rate):
    try:
        ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate, timeout=1)
        while True:
            if ser.in_waiting > 0:
                data = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip()
                if data:
                    print(f"Received data: {data}")
    except serial.SerialException as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    finally:
        if ser.is_open:
            ser.close()

Hope this will help, if you have more question, feel free to aks

Unfortunately, without more details about the problem, I cannot provide a more accurate answer.
